# Use Firestore to store critical values in Big Query

Tags: database, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-bigquery

I need Big Query to efficiently analyse TB large datasets.

Every couple of seconds I need to check the maximum and minimum value from some column in the big query table. Even with an appropriate clustering this has become quite expensive.

Would it make sense to store these values in a separate firestore database? Any thoughts? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presumably you know the min and max values from the previous time you checked,  so you should only need to check the min and max values from the new data that has arrived since the last check. You don't need to query the whole table every time.

Comment: right, however, even when I only check a very small fraction of the data in the table (with correct partitioning) it becomes too expensive if I check these values every couple seconds. Do you think I should store these critical values in a different type of database like firestore?